# Problem saving a spreadsheet as *.csv using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

The problem is that I am trying to save this spreadsheet (that I already have opened and saved as *.xlsx) as a *.csv file and I am having the error Runtime error 1004 Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed.

This is for Excel 2016.

```
Dim FilePath as string

FilePath = "U:\CAP Data - Every Month\ISEAdHoc\" & FileMonth & FileYear & "\"

Dim ISEAdHoc_FileName_CSV As String

ISEAdHoc_FileName_CSV = "ISEAdHoc_" & FileMonth & "CAP_" & Format(Now(), "YYYYMMDD") & "_" & Format(Now(), "HHMMSS")

Dim FileNameforCSVandPath As String

FileNameforCSVandPath = FilePath & ISEAdHoc_FileName_CSV & ".csv"

Sheets("ISEAdHoc").Activate

'ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:=FilePath & ISEAdHoc_FileName_CSV, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False, Local:=True

Workbooks(FileNameforCSVandPath).Close SaveChanges:=True
```

I expect to save the file as a *.csv. But for some reason I keep getting the error "Runtime error 1004 Method 'SaveAs' of object '_Workbook' failed." Please help!

Comment: If I can suggest taking the approach laid out in [this answer from today](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56528795/9245853), I think you'll find your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Your code seems to work fine as-is. Verify that your `U:` drive mapped correctly.

I was able to copy your code and it worked on my side.

Comment: Do not post questions as answers please.

Comment: @Damian eh, it's a legit reason for the code to be failing, and at 40 rep one cannot post comments - edited into a statement

Comment: @MathieuGuindon like it is now, yes. But he was asking to the OP. that wasn't an answer.